# How can I access a field of a Parse.com Object when I don't know the fieldname?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

When I use the code below to access a class row for the current user?
Parse reports that the function returns a data set thus:

```
{"user":{"__type":"Pointer""className":"_User""objectId":"NFYHCP6Ftw"}
"known_fieldname":"Value"
"known_fn2":"value2"
"known_fn3":"value3"
"objectId":"obFbHtMW4E"
"createdAt":"2014-09-16T15:47:55.047Z"
"updatedAt":"2014-09-16T16:10:55.318Z"
"__type":"Object"
"className":"Answers"}
```

Parse CloudCode:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("Answers", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Answers");
    query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
    query.first({
        success: function(obj) {
            // kick out "value"...
            console.log("A field I know="+obj.get("known_fieldname"));
            // this for loop doesn't loop thru the field "keys" and "values"
            // what do I replace it with?
            for (var key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    console.log("Answer="+obj.get(key));
                    // add to a dictionary to return to caller
                }
            }
            response.success(obj);
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("Failed to get any answers.");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of keys for an Object one needs to do this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj.toJSON());
```

One can then loop thru keys thus:

```
for (var key in keys) { ...
```

I think the Parse developers assumed one would know the names of fields within a Parse class and so didn't provide (yet) a clean API to access them.